# quadrature demodulator on a chip

Tags: rtl-sdr

I am searching for a single chip/small board solution for quadrature demodulation to sample IQ signals with an integrated ADC for DC-50Mhz frequencies.

The reason for that is that I found [this sdr transceiver](http://hiqsdr.com/images/7/7c/HiQTRX_V24T_B.pdf) and I was wondering if sampling could be performed on a single chip with IQ outputs

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there are no ICs that perform just quadrature demodulation. If you did this, you'd no longer have an SDR as there would be no software, and having discarded the constraint of reprogrammability, there's usually a simpler hardware solution.

However, demodulation is commonly performed in FPGAs or DSPs in these situations, yielding the advantages of dedicated hardware (as opposed to performing it on a desktop computer), while retaining the programmable nature of SDRs. In the schematic you link, the very large IC in the middle is an FPGA. It's common in wideband SDRs like this for the FPGA to be responsible only for filtering some narrow band(s) out of the received signal and sending them, via ethernet, elsewhere for further processing. [HPSDR](http://openhpsdr.org/) and [SDRstick](http://sdrstick.com/) are other SDRs intended to work this way.

But you could also add another DAC, audio amplifier, and speaker and program the FPGA to perform your desired demodulation directly. The radios by [Elecraft](http://www.elecraft.com/) are an example.